# Website refuses headless chrome connections

Tags: google-chrome, http, web-scraping, https, google-chrome-headless

Im trying to implement simple scraper, however I encoutered some problem. Somehow website is refusing connections from  headless chrome. This is first and the only request, there is no any javascript execution. Requests from normal chrome works well so it's definitly not a banned ip. What can be wrong here? How are they posibly detecting it?

I'm running normal headless chrome and then I replace user agent, that's all.

`.\chrome.exe --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222`

```
General:
  Request URL: https://www.adidas.de/
  Request Method: GET
  Status Code: 403 
  Remote Address: 23.210.248.137:443
  Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
  cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
  content-length: 1952
  content-type: text/html
  date: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 16:16:49 GMT
  expires: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 16:16:49 GMT
  pragma: no-cache
  status: 403

Request Headers:
  :authority: www.adidas.de
  :method: GET
  :path: /
  :scheme: https
  accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
  accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
  cache-control: max-age=0
  sec-fetch-mode: navigate
  sec-fetch-site: none
  sec-fetch-user: ?1
  upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
  user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: To solve your specific problem, you need to obtain Telerik Fiddler or Wireshark and observe the interactions between chrome and the website.  Your job will be to mimic those interactions using your headless browser.  In particular, pay attention to the User-Agent information.

Comment: Could you please share the request dumps both from Chrome in noral mode and from headless Chrome? Is there any difference? Also pay attention for redirections 30x (tick checkbox "Preserve log" on network tab in Chrome developer tools).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have no idea what can cause that but Fiddler doesn't allow to pass request to chrome, and it happens only in headless mode. However in normal mode it's very first request, right after http CONNECT packet to I assume it has to be the same in headless mode.

Comment: @omegastripes Ok, I was quite sure that there was no difference but headless didn't send Accept-Language and that was a problem.

Comment: Please post that as the answer, it could be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

@RobertHarvey: Yes, you are correct: sending Accept-Language is a must for some websites. You can either do it with puppeteer via their API, or with chrome-remote-interface by intercepting requests and adding header directly.